# URL content to HdfsBolt

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

In the ES topology I would like to index urls in ElasticSearch and forward a tuple of (url, [title, content]) to an Hdfs storage. I found that Apache-storm has a proper Hdfs [bolt](https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.2.1/storm-hdfs.html) which looks like a straight forward implementation. I would like to know where to look for this tuple in the ES crawling topology. Could you point which bolt has this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need not only the textual content but also the metadata as this is where the title gets stored. Look at what the [JSoupParserBolt](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/3c86d9b5ce89b9a07233c93fbda182ff7a48828c/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/bolt/JSoupParserBolt.java#L388) emits on the default stream and connect the HDFS bolt to its output.

This is similar to what we do with the [WARC module](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/external/warc) which extends the HDFS bolt, except the WARC bolt does not require anything from the parsing step and can be connected straight to the output of the Fetcher.